# How can I pass a C++ struct to a C# DLL method using COM interop

Tags: c#, c++, com, interop

I currently have a C# project which is compiled into a COM interop DLL containing the following:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace CommonTest
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public interface ICommonTest
    {
        [DispId(1)]
        int Test(int a, int b);
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class CommonTestManaged : ICommonTest
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// A method to test the creation of a managed DLL built in C#. It's functionality just adds together two numbers.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="a">Number 1</param>
        /// <param name="b">Number 2</param>
        /// <returns>The sum of numbers a and b</returns>
        public int Test(int a, int b)
        {
            return a + b;
        }
    }
}
```

On the C++ side, this method is successfully called with the following:

```
void Usage()
{
    CoInitialize(nullptr);
    ICommonTestPtr pICommonTest(__uuidof(CommonTestManaged));

    long lResult = 0;
    pICommonTest->Test(5, 10, &lResult);

    CoUninitialize();
}
```

My question is, is there a way to pass a C++ struct as an parameter of Test() so that I can access its contents in C#?

Comment: Please show the struct definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the struct definition and types (it must describable by a type library), but yes, you can create a struct like this in C#

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Test
{
    public int Value1;
    public int Value2;
    etc...
}
```

Use it like this in the interface (and implement it in the class):

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface ICommonTest
{
    void Test(ref Test test);
}
```

The Visual Studio `#import` directive will generate code like this in the .tlh file:

```
struct __declspec(uuid("d80d27a3-7643-39bf-bba8-c8cc0ab10e7e"))
Test
{
    long Value1;
    long Value2;
    etc...
};
```

And you can use like this in C++:

```
ICommonTestPtr pICommonTest(__uuidof(CommonTestManaged));

Test t = {};
t.Value2 = 123456789;
pICommonTest->Test(&t);
```

Comment: That's great thanks. Could you refer me to any documentation on this?

Comment: Difficult to say, this spans multiple technologies and the way they interact, you have COM, .NET, Type Libraries, etc. The closest here is probably p/invoke https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/pinvoke but COM interop is not exactly the same as p/invoke. Plus it depends on .NET Framework vs .NET Core they are not 100% equivalent with respect to COM support...